# Need assistance retrieving all the tasks for a HierarchicalRequirement using the .NET Rest API

Tags: rally

I'm using the following code to retrieve all the HierarchicalRequirements and the child tasks, but the Children element never has any entries:

```
restApi = new RallyRestApi(username,pswd,url,"1.24");

//Build request
Request request = new Request("HierarchicalRequirement"); //HierarchicalRequirement
request.Fetch = new List<string>()
{
    "Name",
    "Description",
    "FormattedID",
    "Iteration",
    "Actuals",
    "PlanEstimate",
    "WorkProduct",
    "Children"
};

//Make request and process results
QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(request);

//loop through each user story
foreach (var result in queryResult.Results)
{
    //loop through each task
    foreach (var child in result["Children"])
    {
       //do something
    }
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Children is the collection of child stories on an epic. 
If you want the list of Tasks that are attached to a story you will need to use the Tasks attribute.

```
{
"Tasks"
};

//Make request and process results
QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(request);

//loop through each user story
foreach (var result in queryResult.Results)
{
    //loop through each task
    foreach (var child in result["Tasks"])
    {
       //do something
    }
}
```